# How do I change the typeface from bold to normal for text written on the table of contents pages?

Tags: table-of-contents, bold

In the table of contents, the chapter number and chapter name are bold while the section and subsection numbers and names are not bold. How do I remove the bold from the chapter number and chapter name on the table of contents pages?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few packages that can help customize `\tableofcontents`, `\listoffigures`, `\listoftables`, and other entries- here's a solution using the [`titletoc`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/titletoc) package.

[image: screenshot]

The important bit from the code below is

```
\titlecontents{chapter}
[0pt]                                               % left margin
{}%
{\contentsmargin{0pt}                               % numbered entry format
    \thecontentslabel\enspace%
    \large}
{\contentsmargin{0pt}\large}                        % unnumbered entry format
{\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\contentspage}                 % filler-page format (e.g dots)
[]                                                  % below code (e.g vertical space)
```

Have a look at the documentation for more examples/ Here's a complete MWE to play with.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\titlecontents{chapter}
[0pt]                                               % left margin
{}%
{\contentsmargin{0pt}                               % numbered entry format
    \thecontentslabel\enspace%
    \large}
{\contentsmargin{0pt}\large}                        % unnumbered entry format
{\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\contentspage}                 % filler-page format (e.g dots)
[]                                                  % below code (e.g vertical space)


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test one}
\loop
\section{Section text}
\begin{table}
    \caption{Test table two}
\end{table}
\ifnum\value{section}<5\repeat

\chapter{Test two}
\loop
\section{Section text}
\begin{table}
    \caption{Test table two}
\end{table}
\ifnum\value{section}<5\repeat

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10):

I assume you're using the `report` or `book` document class, or a class that's based on these classes.

If you use the [tocloft](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) package, you can use the macros `\cftchapfont` and `\cftchappagefont` to set the font size and weight used for chapter-level entries and associated page numbers in the ToC. Set these macros to `\mdseries` to achieve your objective.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftchapfont{\mdseries}
\renewcommand\cftchappagefont{\mdseries}
\setlength\textwidth{3in} % just for this example
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First}
\section{Hello}
\subsection{Good morning}
\subsection{Good evening}
\chapter{Second}
\section{Goodbye}
\end{document}
```

The Table-of-Contents part of the output generated by this MWE looks like this:

[image]

For comparison, here's what the ToC would look like *without* the `\cftsec...` macro redefinitions -- note the bold font used for the sections' numbers, headers, and page numbers:

[image]

---

Addendum: If you use the `article` document class (which doesn't feature `\chapter`-level divisions, you'll find that the section-level entries (and associated page numbers) in the ToC are printed in bold. If you want to change these entries from "bold" to "normal", you can use the `tocloft` package; just be sure to redefine the macros `\cftsecfont` and `\cftsecpagefont` (instead of `\cftchapfont` and `\cftchappagefont`).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but the code did not cause any change in the output.

Comment: @PeterPalmer - I had overlooked that you were dealing with *chapter* rather than *section* headers in the ToC. I've changed the MWE; it's now based on the `book` document class and features code to change the appearance of chapter-level headings in the ToC.

Comment: It's nice to see this approach - I find the syntax of this package slightly harder to grasp than the `titletoc`

Comment: @cmhughes - the `tocloft` package provides lots and lots of ways of changing the look of the ToC (and LoT, LoF,...). It's probably true that the sheer number of actions made possible by the package can be a bit dizzying at first.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a TOC entry, formatted the line as you would like it. Compile with two passes.

```latex
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\normalfont\textit{This Entry will exists without being bold, also it will be italicized. }}
```