# Eliminate Bold Font from ToC Only

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script

Is there a way to generate the table of contents so that there is no bold character formatting?
(other than using a font that does not have a bold face)

Komascript.

Some of the chapter headings in the text block are in bold, while others are not. It would be preferable to go through and change them all, but given the size of the text, I'm trying to avoid that task. Plus, I can't just go in and delete all instances of \textbf{} since some are needed.

I tried using these two commands under the tocloft package as recommended in this answer:

```
\renewcommand\cftchapfont{\mdseries}
\renewcommand\cftchappagefont{\mdseries}
```

([How do I change the typeface from bold to normal for text written on the table of contents pages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115481/how-do-i-change-the-typeface-from-bold-to-normal-for-text-written-on-the-table-o)) but there was no effect.

The tocloft package doesn't play well with the Koma classes, perhaps there is a native Koma way of producing the desired output?

MWE:

```
     \documentclass{scrbook}
   

   \usepackage{blindtext}

  \begin{document}
  \tableofcontents

   \part[Glossary of Defined Terms]{\textbf {Glossary of Defined Terms}}
  \blindtext[3]
  \chapter[von Kleist]{von Kleist}
    \blindtext[4]
    \section{Chili}
    \blindtext[3]

  \end{document}
```

Perhaps there's a way to put the entire ToC inside an environment, like:

```
\being{normaltext}
\end{normaltext}
```

?

Comment: I recommend providing a complete code example to illustrate your request.

Comment: In a regular document the chapter titles (`\chapter{title}`) are all set in the same font.  Show us what you have done so some are in different fonts.

Comment: I don't think that will really help, but I've added a MWE. I need for none of the various structural components to display a bold font. There's chapter, part, section, subsection and sub subsection.

Comment: I need for none of the various structural components to display a bold font. There's chapter, part, section, subsection and sub subsection. I used MinionPro because it's relatively common and has both a bold and a Roman face.

Comment: You are correct that your MWE does not help. I don't have the Minion Pro font. You do not have multiple chapters or sections that could use different fonts than normal. If you want help then please help by providing an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we can compile that shows your problem. (Your MWE basically only shows the class but not your problematic code).

Comment: Koma sets different structural components in different typefaces in the ToC. I'm looking to see if there is a general override. You'll note that in the compiled MWE the \section entry in the ToC is normal text, while everything else is bold. The point is that if you choose a font that *doesn't* have a bold typeface, the issue cannot arise. I'll change it to LaTeX defaults, the behavior is the same.

Comment: I tried to refine the question.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```latex
\AfterTOCHead[toc]{\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalcolor\normalfont}}
```

If you want to do the same for LoF and LoT, remove the optional argument

```latex
\AfterTOCHead{\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalcolor\normalfont}}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\AfterTOCHead{\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalcolor\normalfont}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part{Glossary of Defined Terms}
\blindtext[3]
\chapter{von Kleist}
\blindtext[4]
\section{Chili}
\blindtext[3]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

`\addtokomafont{partentry}{\mdseries}` and `\addtokomafont{chapterentry}{\mdseries}` in the preamble of your example will take care of the bold formatting.

Edit:

`\addtokomafont{disposition}{\mdseries}` will modify all sectioning levels.

Comment: I added these, then added \addtokomafont{sectionentry}{\mdseries} and 
\addtokomafont{subsectionentry}{\mdseries} and got the following error message:
% Package scrkbase Error: font of element `sectionentry' can't be extended

Comment: That may occur because a modification for sectionentry via `\addtokomafont` or `\setkomafont` is only available for the scrartcl class (table 3.2. in my Koma-script documentation).

Comment: It doesn't seem that there is a way to set up an environment in Koma where bold fonts cannot be displayed. Oh well. There's only 600 pages to go through...

Comment: What about `\let\bfseries\mdseries` in your preamble? That should get rid of bold altogether.